# Copying DataContext from one usercontrol to another

Tags: c#, wpf

I have several instances of a `Usercontrol`called "ChannelControls" which contains quite a few different basic control : sliders, combobox, buttons etc.

But it also contains a `Usercontrol` I made :

```
<CMiX:CMiXListBox  x:Name="FileNameList"
        SelectionChanged="FileNameList_SelectionChanged"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        AllowDrop="True"
        PreviewDrop="FileListBox_Drop"
        PreviewMouseDown="FileNameList_PreviewMouseDown"
        PreviewMouseMove="FileListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
        Template="{DynamicResource BaseListBoxControlStyle}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CMiX:FileSelector}}}"
        SelectionMode="{Binding ModeSelection,Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CMiX:FileSelector}}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="DeleteFileName" Content="X" Click="DeleteFileName_Click" Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}" 
                        Padding="4" BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        Background="Transparent" 
                        Foreground="{StaticResource BaseText}" 
                        Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DeleteFileName}"/>
                <TextBlock Padding="4" Text="{Binding FileName, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource PathToFileName}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseListBoxItemStyle}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding FileIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</CMiX:CMiXListBox>
```

Now when I copy and paste the `DataContext` from one instance of ChannelControls to another, every controls are updated correctly but then, this "CMiXListBox" is now linked to the one that the data comes from. Which means that any change are happening on any other that have received the new `DataContext`.

This is how the copy and paste is happening :

```
ChannelData copy = new ChannelData();

private void LayerButton_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Key == Key.C && ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control))
    {
        foreach(ChannelControls cc in Utils.FindVisualChildren<ChannelControls>(cmix))
        {
            if(cc.IsVisible == true)
            {
                copy = (ChannelData)cc.DataContext;
            }
        }
    }

    if (e.Key == Key.V && ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control))
    {
        foreach (ChannelControls cc in Utils.FindVisualChildren<ChannelControls>(cmix))
        {
            if (cc.IsVisible == true && copy != null)
            {
                cc.EnabledOSC = false;

                cc.DataContext = (ChannelData)copy.Clone();

                message.SendAll(cc.DataContext, cc.Name);
                cc.EnabledOSC = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I think there is something going on with the `ItemsSources`, any idea ? thx

Comment: There appear to be multiple issues.  The most likely cause of the problem is your implementation of Clone() which you haven't shown us.  ChannelData is apparently a list of some kind and so to properly clone a list you need to clone each element.  Second you seem to setting the singleton copy field multiple times...how can this be right?  Third, instead of playing DataContext hacky sack why not have a proper view model?  Fourth a proper implementation of copy/paste really needs to use the clipboard. And I have run out of space.

Comment: Hi, ChannelData is a class with different properties like string, ObservableCollection<string>, double, Media.Color etc. I have tried Clipboard a little but some properties can't be serialized.. like Media.Color for example.